# sql query?? how to print all those columns having same id in one row. Can anyone tell the DB2 equivalent also

Tags: mysql, sql, db2, db2-400

may be this type of question has been already asked, but i couldn't find it...
So i need a little help...  Thanks...

Suppose i have a table  TABLE1 as...

```
----------------------
stdcode  |    value  | 
----------------------
1        |     AA    |
----------------------
1        |     AA    |
----------------------
1        |     AC    |
----------------------
1        |     BB    |
----------------------
2        |     BA    |
----------------------
2        |     BD    |
----------------------
```

and i want to write a sql query which prints the result as...

```
1 AA;AA;AC;BB
2 BA;BD
```

DB2 equivalent syntax also required....

Comment: You couldn't find it? Did you look?

Comment: @Strawberry yup i did...  i think i didn't use a good search term while googling.... Thats why i already mentioned that it may be already asked...  anyways..  thanks...

Comment: db2 equivalent please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `group_concat()`:

```
select stdcode, group_concat(value separator ';') as values
from table1
group by stdcode;
```

Comment: thanks for the edit and the solution....

Comment: can you tell the db2 equivalent syntax

Comment: @AshwaniKumarRahul . . . db2 doesn't have a simple function for this purpose.  Alas.